# How to pass method from Fragment to DialogFragment? Xamarin/Android

Tags: android, xamarin

In my Activity I have Fragment (ContactBox) which contains "Send" button. If this button`s action fails, user sees error (DialogFragment). I want to implement "Try Again" button on this error, but I dont know how to pass retry action from first Fragment to second DialogFragment. Do you have any ideas? Retry method is placed in ContactBoxFragment.

Comment: Too vague as written. Add to question the code that you have, for these fragments. Especially anything involving the Send button and the Retry method. Then someone can help you. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: why do you need to pass a method?  Can't the dialog just return a value indicating the user's choice?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.